# Getting Response 200 instead of data from API call

Tags: python, encoding

I am new here so pardon me for mistakes or silly questions
I am trying to implement following via python
https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/cortex/cortex-xdr/cortex-xdr-api/cortex-xdr-apis/xql-apis/get-xql-query-exported-data.html
Intsead of data, I am getting <Response 200>
How can I get the GZIP file via this API call. This is the first time I am trying anything like this and any help would be appreciated.
My code:

```
def get_stream_data():
    temp_headers = {
        "x-xdr-auth-id": str(4),
        "Authorization": config['CORTEX_KEY'],
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        
    }
    stream_id = get_XQL_query()
    data_temp = {"request_data":{"stream_id":stream_id,"is_gzip_compressed": True}}
   
    response = requests.post(url="<fqdn>.paloaltonetworks.com/public_api/v1/xql/get_query_results_stream/",headers=temp_headers,json=data_temp)
    
    #something here to parse the response, no idea what
    return response
```

Comment: Check `dir(response)` Maybe you need `response.content` or `response.text` or something alike?

Answer (score 0):

Requests library [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp) says that you need:

```py
return response.json()   # Returns JSON, if properly encoded else raises error
# or
return response.content  # Return raw bytes
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I already tried both and got nothing. response.json gave error that function was expecting some value and response.content gave :
```
77\xb2\x19\x02\xeb$\xe1\xc8J\x9b\xaa\xfbE\xa3\x89\xdc!A\xec\'\xcd0~\xd2x4\xd2\xd9\xca\x89\xfe\x84f\x15Z1\xb8\xda\xc9\x8b\x8f\xfa\xf0\xf2\x91\xe4\xa8Z[\x10\x89f\xfa\x90\xaa\x00\xc4\xc6\xe1<d\xcf\xe2\xf8\x94\x9b\x04_1"
```

Comment: It may be that you are receiving gziped content, so you need to unzip it yourself, example here: https://coderwall.com/p/eyadkg/http-request-response-with-compressed-body-in-python

Or you can update the header to be the default value `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",`